# Make knockout "visible" use CSS "visibility" property

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

According to [the "visible" binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html), Knockout uses `display: none` to hide elements if the the value of `visible` evaluates to `false`. How can I make it use `visibility: hidden` instead? `visibility: hidden` has the advantage (in this case) of still making the element take up space on the page.

Comment: You can use a [style](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) or [css](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use plain css style or classes, check the official [knockout.js css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) or [knockout.js style binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) documentations.

Style binding example :

```
<div data-bind="style: { visibility: isVisible()  ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }">
    Profit Information
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        isVisible: ko.observable(true) // visible
    };
    viewModel.isVisible(false); // hidden
</script>
```